# php error Fatal error: Call to a member function get()

Tags: php, mysql

I getting an error like:

> Notice: Undefined property: CedTagViewTag::$pagination

and

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get()

This is the part of the code where I'm getting the error:

```
(($this->show_pagination == 1 || ($this->show_pagination == 2)) && ($this->pagination->get('pages.total') > 1)) { ?>
<div class="pagination">
```

How can I resolve it?
this is whole code

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

require_once (JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');
require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_cedtag/helpers/themes.php';

// to reuse components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php
// when doing later $this->loadTemplate('item');
$this->addTemplatePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/views  /category/tmpl');
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_cedtag/helpers');
//blog_item.php use icon.php
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers');

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet('media/com_cedtag/css/blog.css');

$cedTagsHelper = new CedTagsHelper();
if ($this->tagDescription) {
      $document->setDescription($cedTagsHelper->truncate($this->tagDescription));
} else {
$document->setDescription($cedTagsHelper->truncate($this->tag));
}

$document->setTitle($this->title);
$document->setMetadata('keywords', $this->tag);

$CedTagThemes = new CedTagThemes();
$CedTagThemes->addCss();

?>

<h1><?php echo JText::_('COM_CEDTAG_POSTS_TAGGED') . " " . JText::_('\'') . $this->tag . JText::_('\'') ?></h1>
<?php if (isset($this->showDescription) && $this->showDescription && ($this->tagDescription != null)) { ?>
<div class="category-desc">
<?php echo $this->tagDescription; ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<?php if (isset($this->ads_top_use) && $this->ads_top_use) { ?>
<div class="cedTagAdsTopContent">
<?php  echo $this->ads_top_content; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php
if (isset($this->results) && !empty($this->results)) {
foreach ($this->results as $item) {
    $this->item = & $item;
    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
}
} ?>

<?php
if (isset($this->ads_bottom_use) && $this->ads_bottom_use) {
?>
<div class="cedTagAdsBottomContent">
<?php  echo $this->ads_bottom_content; ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<?php if (($this->show_pagination == 1 || ($this->show_pagination == 2)) && ($this->pagination->get('pages.total') > 1)) { ?>
<div class="pagination">
<?php if ($this->show_pagination_results) { ?>
<p class="counter">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter(); ?>
</p>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: any frameworks there??

Comment: How is $pagination declared and where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error(s) can be logically explained.

> Notice: Undefined property: CedTagViewTag::$pagination

Is because the property "pagination" (I think you are accessing it statically?) is not defined, it doesn't exist. It'd be the same thing (for all purposes of an example) if you tried to access a variable that hasn't been defined.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get()

<strike>Although this may not be related, it could be explained by the previous error.</strike> It is related. The part causing it is in your `if` conditional:

`&& ($this->pagination->get('pages.total') > 1))`

You are calling `get()` method on `pagination`, then you will get this error, because you are trying to call a method on an undefined property! To resolve this, I'd suggest properly viewing the object and how is it being instantiated and resolving `pagination` since it is obviously undefined as well as including what frameworks or how pagination is instantiated for a clearer picture and a better answer.